Should sudo ask for root password?
I recently switched to Kubuntu Linux from Windows, where I had a separate admin user, and a default user for everyday tasks. I made a script that makes usual login as admin impossible, just so that I don't accidentally log in as admin (mainly for security reasons). So to make some changes as admin, I (or anyone using my computer) would have to provide admin password when prompted. I liked this setup, because it seems to be more secure than just always running as an admin user.
On Linux, login as root is disabled by default, which I totally understand why. To make changes as root, one needs to precede a command with sudo, and provide user password, not root password (given the user is part of sudoers). I understand how the mechanism of it works, and what users may use sudo at all. My question is, is it a good idea to make sudo ask for root password and not my password? I mean, in Windows I had to provide admin password to make changes as admin, is it a good idea to do the same on Linux? Or should I leave it be?
I am the only person using my computer and don't give out my credentials to anyone, if it matters.
UPD: Now it makes total sense to me, thanks to David's answer. Basically, in Windows terms, Standard (created by default) user in Linux = Admin user in Windows. Well, kind of: standard Linux user is privileged to be elevated to root, but they're not the root. What sudo does is it asks for user password because user is privileged (I know, mindblowing, but I didn't understand it until now). The same is kind of true for Windows (at least 10 and 11): admin user can't do anything they want, they are still prompted with the UAC, they are just privileged to just press 'yes' instead of typing the password. I've been retyping this edit for half an hour and I don't know how to explain it in better words. The mix up was that I didn't connect the dots properly in my head.

If it asks for root password, there would be not much point left. If you want the "Windows-style" you mentioned instead, there is su, but it's less convenient and/or more complicated if you want to execute command with it "directly" (instead of getting a root shell).

It should be made clear.  You can make other users but they will NOT be root. Even if you grant them sudo permissions they will NOT be root. Access to the root should be restricted to only those users who need access.  Sudo should be used to in-place of using root whenever possible.  This of course requires services to be properly configured to not run as root otherwise all their files will be owned and only accessible by root

The "UPD" to your question is inaccurate. The user created by default when Kubuntu was installed is an Administrator. Most commands execute as the user who invoked the command. However, sudo and su execute as the root user regardless of the user who invoked the command. If necessary, these commands then authenticate (by asking for a proper user password) before proceeding.

@DavidAnderson Sorry, I don't quite understand the inaccuracy here. I edited the question to explain my initial misunderstanding, and I think it is pretty accurate. Can you please elaborate on what exactly isn't correct in my UPD? Or even suggest a correction to my question.


Should sudo ask for root password?

No, that is what su (substitute user) does. By default, su asks for the root password. If you specify a different user, the password of the different user is asked for. See the examples given latter in this answer for where a different user is given.

My question is, is it a good idea to make sudo ask for root password and not my password?

Well, if you are a standard user, then neither the root password or your password is going to be accepted. If you are an administrator user and you feel this is a problem, then don't login in as an administrator.

I mean, in Windows I had to provide admin password to make changes as admin, is it a good idea to do the same on Linux?

In Kubuntu, you to provide administrator password to make changes as administrator and administrator password to make changes as a standard user. Windows basically works the same way.

Or should I leave it be?

Yes. You can try to make some sort of custom changes, but this should be unnecessary, since Kubuntu is already setup like Windows.

Authentication under Linux
The rest of this answer was tested using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Desktop Linux.
In your question you state "... from Windows, where I had a separate admin user, and a default user for everyday tasks". The same is true for Linux. You can create standard user and administrator user accounts. Say user rpj is a standard user and user dma is an administrator user.
For dma to become the root user, this user would enter the following, where the password for dma would be asked for.
sudo -s

To execute a single command as root, the following would be entered, where the password for dma would be asked for.
sudo command

For rpj to become the root user, this user would enter the following, where the password for dma would be asked for twice.
su -P -c 'sudo -s' dma

To execute a single command as root, the following would be entered, where the password for dma would be asked for twice.
su -P -c 'sudo command' dma

For other tasks performed by standard user rpj which require authentication, the password for administrator dma would be asked for instead of the password for standard user rpj. For example, if standard user rpj tried to add a new user, the password for the administrator dma would be asked for, as shown below. (See the answer posted by user murn for a far better explanation.)


So you suggest creating a setup similar to my old Windows setup, i.e. creating new user and giving him privileges to use sudo and another user without these privileges?

When you install Windows, the first user is an administrator. You then add standard user accounts. The same is true for most Linux distributions. Administrators automatically have sudo privileges and standard users do not. It might be useful for you to state which Linux distribution you are using.

For example, Debian Linux is different. During installation, the first user is a standard user and you set a separate password for the root user.

I use Kubuntu (basically Ubuntu), I was only prompted to create the password for the user I created, which was not the root user. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think your answer is more about creating a similar double-user setup on Linux, rather than utilizing root as the admin user. That said, your answer is still helpful as I may consider using this setup instead of the one I described in my question.

I guess I did not directly answer your questions. I updated my answer to do so. I see this as the current situation. You have an administrator and a standard user account on Windows. You only have an administrator account on Kubuntu. If this correct, then you need to create a standard user account for your personal use on Kubuntu.

I should add, if you are thinking of setting up Kubuntu so the root can login like an administrator or standard user, then you should have made that clearer in your question. Doing so would be a bad idea. See the question Why is it bad to log in as root?.

No, I'm not thinking of making it possible to log in as root in any way, I mentioned in my question that I understand why it's disabled by default. On your answer update: I guess I mixed up the intent behind admin users and root user. I see now that my standard user on Linux (the one created during installation) is analogous to admin user on Windows. I initially thought it to be a standard user (non-admin).

@DavidAnderson Almost. If you leave root password blank, root account will be disabled, sudo package will be installed and first user (created during system installation) will be allowed to use sudo (see). Side note: Some tools eg. in case of system recovery, needs root password, so setting it manually after installation is still a good idea.

First, there are generally three commonly available ways to do something as another user: sudo, mentioned in the question, su, mentioned in David Anderson's answer, and Polkit.

sudo usually asks for your password, and is highly configurable. Popular distros add the first created user to a group (sudo for the Debian family, wheel for the Red Hat family, etc.), and have a rule allowing that group to do anything. This is typically what makes a user an admin on such distros, instead of actually having to login as root.
However, su is far less configurable. Usually it is configured by its PAM stack, where some distros might have rules allowing only particular groups.
The third option, Polkit, is almost always going to be what's involved when you get a GUI prompt (like the one in the last screenshot in David Anderson's answer). Polkit is also very highly configurable, and most distros treat it much the same as sudo, using the same group to grant access. However, the configuration is completely independent - it's just that the same group is often used by default. If you add some config for a specific user in sudoers, that will do nothing for Polkit privileges.

There are other options like doas or run0, but these aren't as widely used yet, so I'm ignoring these for this post.
Now for authentication:

Usually, sudo asks for your password, but it can be configured to ask for the target user's password (target_pw), which in practice is usually root, so root's password, or root's password even if you want to run something as another user (root_pw). While there might be situations where these might make sense, in the general case for a shared system, I'll say it's a terrible idea. Don't do it. Either:

This will lead to password sharing, which will greatly increase the risk of leaks and complicate password rotation if it does get leaked. You should be using a password manager, which would mitigate the issues, but why add a complication and then mitigate it when the status quo is just fine?

Or you'll have to have someone who knows the password come and enter it, in which case they could use su in combination with sudo like suggested in David Anderson's answer for one-off tasks.


If it is for a single-user system which you administer and you want to enter another password for sensitive actions, sure, go for it. In this case, basically it's mainly a matter of personal feelings. Will it really increase security? Depends on what you're defending against, but for the average user, I'd say it doesn't add anything.

Polkit will ask for your password if your user is authorized to do whatever action you're trying to do, or for any user's that can. If your user is not authorized and multiple other users are, then it will ask you to select which user to authenticate as and prompt for that user's credentials. So Polkit offers the best of both worlds: you can authenticate your user for actions it can do, and for actions for which another user needs to authenticate, they can enter their password. There's no need for sharing passwords in either case.
Note that Polkit has a command-line tool, pkexec, which can be used to run commands as root or another user.


So you could ignore sudo and su altogether and use only Polkit. In practice, of course, third-party tools might only support sudo, so you won't have a choice, but if you can control what is being used, then going Polkit-only is an option.

Welcome to Linux.  As you've noticed, Linux works permissions differently than does Windows.  For this discussion we'll think of a Windows Admin account as being similar to a Linux root account.  That is not strictly accurate (stay your hands, my security-minded friends!) but for this discussion it should be sufficient.
Personally, I do not like how Windows manages elevation.  You must open the entire application (like a PowerShell terminal) as an Admin to run a command as an Admin.  If you leave that application open, any subsequent action is taken as an Admin.
In Linux we'll chunk up the world into those with sudo and those without.  There are pros and cons to each, but I prefer sudo.  I think that's true for most.  Running sudo is like saying "for this one command here I want elevation".  Be appropriately cautious whenever you start a command pipeline with sudo:  you are elevating (running as-if root).
No standard user can successfully run sudo.  In fact, a clever admin can carefully craft sudo, tailoring it to a specific user, so that user can only elevate for as little as a single command for example.
I recommend, of course, unique passwords/accounts for each person to whom you give access to any computer.  Each user will have their own password and you (as the admin) will make decisions about whether and to what purpose any specific user may use sudo.  (Your GUI on Kubuntu should allow you to choose Standard v Administrator for each user account you create; more detailed changes will require terminal action.)
This type of individual elevation also allows for the logging of who has done what, something any shared credentials would obfuscate.
So, to directly answer your question... sudo should always ask for the password of the current user (which should never be root on a system with sudo).
This should augment what David has said in his very detailed response and also address your update.
